# Como puedo invertir un arreglo

Tags: c++, dev-c++, c++11

Quiero invertir solo cierta zona de un arreglo. No todo el arreglo, pero cuando lo hago me invierte un numero de mas, por ejemplo, este es el arreglo:

1 2 4 5 8 7 7 5 5 7 9

Y quiero invertir de solo de la posicion 8 a la 10. Pero al hacer la iversion me cambia de la posicion 7 a la 10. Este es mi codigo.

```
introducir el código aquí
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main(){

int a;

cin>>a;

int arr[a];

for(int i=0; i<a; i++){
    cin>>arr[i];
}

int* r = find(&arr[0],&arr[a],5);
int* t = find(r+1,&arr[a],5);

for(int i=0; i<a; i++){
    if(*r == arr[i] && *t == arr[i]){
        reverse(&arr[0],r);
        reverse(t,&arr[a]);
    }
}

for(int i=0; i<a; i++){
    cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
}   

}
```

Asi es como tiene que dar el resultado en pantalla:

4 2 1 5 8 7 7 5 9 7 5

Answer (score 0):

Si miras la [documentación](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse), la función `reverse` toma como parámetros 2 iteradores.

Tomando el ejemplo que brinda la página, se ejecuta obteniendo iteradores con la función `begin` y `end`

```
int a[] = {4, 5, 6, 7};
std::reverse(std::begin(a), std::end(a));
```

O si prefieres que intercambie del 2º al 5º elemento inclusive:

```
int a[] = {4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
std::reverse(std::begin(a) + 1, std::end(a) - 2);
```

Al inicio le sumas uno porque el segundo elemento sigue justo después del primero. `2 - 1 = 1`

Al final le restas 2 porque el arreglo tiene 7 elementos y el 5º está dos lugares antes de él. `5 - 7 = -2`

Puedes probarlo [aquí](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cc3d1bbea7d5b496).

---

Lo que me parece extraño es que el código no debería compilar por esta línea:

```
int arr[a];
```

`a` es una variable. Debería ser un número  que se pueda saber en tiempo de compilación.

La única forma de tener arreglos dinámicos es con punteros o con alguna clase como `std::vector`.

Comment: Si no le agrego un t+1, al momento de ejecutar el codigo no hace nada, pero si no agrego el t+1 si se ejecuta, pero sigue sin invertir los numero que queiro del arreglo.

Comment: De qué `t` me hablas? Por cierto la función se encarga de invertir la porción de la cadena indicada. No necesitas usarla dentro de ningún for

Comment: En el codigo tengo dos punteros uno que es *r el cual encuentra el primer numero que quiero buscar y el segundo puntero es *t, cuando quiero hacer reverse de t solo invierte la posicion 7 a la 10 pero yo quiero que invierta de la posicon 8 a la 10. Ya le agrege esto reverse(t+1,&arr[a]);  pero no hace nada en cambio si le quito el  +1 si hace el reverse. Es lo que no enteindo por que.

Comment: Porque la función toma iteradores. No punteros.

Comment: Gracias, ya me salio

Comment: Funcionan de una forma similar pero son 2 cosas distintas. De hecho, la función find también toma y regresa iteradores.